# Generating sine, triangle (etc) waves from ttl output of a GPS module (Ublox)

Tags: signal, gps, pll

I'm building a variable frequency standard using a Ublox gps board off Ebay. It'll be hooked up to an Arduino and you enter the desired frequency via a keypad. The signal from the module is a square wave that for some frequencies can show jitter and not really be suitable as a signal generator. I am planning to use it as a way to test and develop a counter I'm also working on.

But is there a way to generate nice clean waveforms that are locked to the ttl signal somehow? I've been reading up on phase locked loop circuits for instance but not sure if that's the way to go.

What I want to do in a nutshell is to send the desired frequency to the gps module and as an option choose to output the signal as a sine/triangle, etc waveform. Just to add some functionality to the device, being able to use it more as a standard signal generator on top of as a reference source.

Frequencies I'm interested in are around 1-1000 000 Hz.

Comment: Why not use a DDS module clocked from the square wave you derive?

Comment: That has also been suggested to me and I'm reading up on that too. From what I understand I could use the gps module as an external reference for the DDS. But I would need a separate input for the DDS to tell it what frequency to generate, it wouldn't automatically "follow" the square wave I generate with the gps module. From an interface perspective it would be neater to have one input (to the gps module) and then have ouputs with the wave form you desire.